# Rxvt Unicode does not display U+E0B0, even though my font includes it

Tags: fonts, urxvt, fontconfig

Unicode / font configuration headaches. I've installed [tmux-powerline](https://github.com/erikw/tmux-powerline) and, per the recommendation, patched my Inconsolata font. The goal here is to display cute little wedge-arrow things, like [U+E0B0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e0b0/index.htm), in the status bar.

For the life of me, I cannot make URxvt display them. Just shows a box.

The patched font is stored in `~/.local/share/fonts`. I am positive that my font cache is up to date. `fc-cache -fv` reports that it successfully caches the folder and `fc-list` includes a line for `Inconsolata for Powerline`.

URxvt is using the correct font. `URxvt*font: xft:Inconsolata for Powerline` is the only `URxvt*font` setting in my `.Xdefaults`. I don't see any other settings in the URxvt man page that look relevant, though there's a lot there I don't understand.

The patched font definitely includes glyphs for these codepoints. `sfddiff` on the original and patched fonts reports that they are included in the patched but are missing from the original.

Per the Arch Wiki, Urxvt ignores any `fonts.conf` solutions or the like. What else can I check to locate the problem? And what's the best font / unicode tutorial you've found on Google, because I'm totally stuck.

Answer (score 8):

rxvt-unicode doesn't support glyphs in the Unicode Private Use Area unless it's compiled with `--enable-unicode3`. This is also explained in [the docs](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/master/troubleshooting.html#urxvt-unicode3-and-frills).

Comment: Nothing like getting feedback from the project owner! Unfortunately I forgot to update the question to note that I do have unicode3 enabled in my build (found that part of the docs later). I'm still poking and prodding at this one; if I figure it out I'll post the answer here, and if appropriate will drop you a comment on GitHub.

Comment: The original link is 404. New direct link to the urxvt item: http://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/master/troubleshooting.html#urxvt-unicode3-and-frills

Comment: Try with `Hack` instead of `Inconsolata`?